# KiCad problem, schematic to PCB layout generates empty PCBnew window

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, footprint

I am using KiCad 5.0.0, after I built my schematic I annotated schematic symbols, assigned PCB footprints to the schematic symbols, then generated the netlist, and finally when I clicked on the tab of Pcbnew to layout printed circuit board it generated a blank Pcbnew file, nothing inside!

Any idea what might causing this problem, please?

Comment: Upgrade to 5.1.4 and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically import the netlist by choosing "Update PCB from Schematic" in Eeschema (default hotkey is F8).

In Pcbnew, to get the netlist if you generate the external file, you need to choose "Import netlist" from the tools menu.

Comment: Great! Worked like charm. Thanks, Seth.

Comment: The update pcb from schematic tool is also in pcbnew (both in the tools menu and in the top toolbar) The import netlist stuff would require you to first export one.